# I really liked the reputation line-graph; can we get something similar back?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, graphs

I really liked the reputation line-graph, but I understand it was problematic. Is there any way that we get something similar back?

Comment: You mean this: [hawkeye's StackExchange repuation graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/93e56396-69f8-4333-b877-1242779e58bf?tab=reputation)?

Comment: Or the Better Mousetrap: http://stackoverflow.com/users/15441/hawkeye?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph  You do have to post to make it move.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this one for your account?

https://stackexchange.com/users/93e56396-69f8-4333-b877-1242779e58bf?tab=reputation

Just click on the "Stack Exchange account" link on your user page and then the reputation tab.